# Read a specific memory address Windows

Tags: c, windows, hardware

We have a challenge that we have some hardware, without a working driver, where we need to check status on the hardware by reading the value from a specific memory address. From what I understand this is a physical memory address that won't change (probably because it's "owned" by the hardware).

So my question; will it even be possible to read this memory address in Windows (10)? And how can I achieve this using C/C++ (idea is to write a wrapper dll to read the memory that will be called by managed C# code)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIHC4.png)

Since it's been 10+ years since I last even looked at C code,, I have tried doing this in managed code (C#), and that fails as expected.

Comment: In order to read a certain physical memory address, I believe that you will have to write a kernel-mode driver using the [Windows Driver Kit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk). I don't think that it is possible to write such a driver using managed code, but you probably can interact with your driver from managed code.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: A kernel driver has to be involved, but that doesn't mean OP has to write it.  For example there is `giveio.sys` which is designed to proxy direct hardware access for user-mode code.

Comment: I see a kernel mode driver can do this. But a utilitylike  RW Portable, https://softfamous.com/portable-rw-read-write-utility, is able to access (read/write) memory, (as far as I know) without a specific kernel mode driver